# for loops with dependencies on pdf with javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

So my Problem right now is, that I am trying to get a for Loop working on my pdf while using acrobat.

Right now i have a table of different Options. each Option has a variable.
I want to sum up the variables in dependency on their Options (so i want to sum up all variables for Option_a for example).
However, I can't get it to work properly.

right now I am trying to solve my Problem with a simpler example

```
var v = 0;
for (var i=1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (this.getField("Text" + i).value == 1) {
         v = v + this.getField("Text" + i).value
    }
}
event.value = v;
```

this works for all Text-fields from 1 to 4, so the sum is 4 at most, if all 4 text fields have the value of 1.
 Now i want only variables to be included in my sum, if another field called "bool" with the same number is 1. So I added 4 new fields named bool1 to bool4 and wrote:

```
var v = 0;
for (var i=1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if (this.getField("bool" + i).value == 1) {
        v = v + this.getField("Text" + i).value
    }
}   
event.value = v;
```

However my sum won't calculate anymore.

Comment: what getField function does?

Comment: Fields are text-entries in pdfs. getField("Text1") just Points to the field with the Name Text1 for example.

Comment: Do you get any error message? What happens when you execute the code in the console?

Comment: i get following error message on BOTH (so also the working one) scripts:`code`:TypeError: this.getField(...) is null
2:Field:Calculate
TypeError: this.getField(...) is null
2:Field:Calculate